# Is there an active digitizer stylus for Dell xps duo 12?

Tags: dell-xps

This hybrid laptop-tablet supports atmel maxTouch technology. However I was unable to find any definitive information on which active digitizer stylus to buy for it. Some sources say active digitizers are not supported at all? Does anyone know an active digitizer supported by this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This laptop, and the Atmel MaxTouch in general, are capacitive-based touch screens.  That means it is integrated into the surface of the screen and that they rely on the conductivity of your fingers to register when you have touched the screen.

An active digitizer, such as a Wacom tablet, is a grid of wires that sits *below* the screen (or other tablet surface) and picks up signals sent from a powered stylus (either wired, battery, or passive pickup from the digitizer itself).

A digitizer has considerably more precision, because the stylus effectively sends a directional beam to the digitizer, allowing the digitizer to determine the exact location and angle of the stylus.  The capacitive screens work by averaging the contact of your fingers to determine where you were intending to touch, thus they are far less accurate.

Unfortunately, while there are [some products](http://www.n-trig.com/) being with both capacitive multi-touch and an active digitizer, yours is not on the list.  The best you would be able to do is a capacitive stylus, which is basically a conductive pen with a little rubber nub on the end.  These do work fairly well by simply reducing the amount of area the table needs to average to determine the point.

---

See http://gigaom.com/2010/03/08/touchscreen-tablets/ if you'd like a more thorough run-down of the differences between the tablet types.